# GridSearchCV Keeps Returning Smallest Alpha for Ridge Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression

I am trying to use data from moneypuck to predict the number of goals an NHL player scored in a given season. I don't expect anyone to look through this but if you want to skim, here is the (rather massive) list of features I kept from the dataset:

```
['team', 'position', 'games_played', 'icetime', 'shifts', 'gameScore', 'onIce_xGoalsPercentage', 'offIce_xGoalsPercentage', 'onIce_corsiPercentage', 'offIce_corsiPercentage', 'onIce_fenwickPercentage', 'offIce_fenwickPercentage', 'iceTimeRank', 'I_F_xOnGoal', 'I_F_xGoals', 'I_F_xRebounds', 'I_F_xFreeze', 'I_F_xPlayStopped', 'I_F_xPlayContinuedInZone', 'I_F_xPlayContinuedOutsideZone', 'I_F_flurryAdjustedxGoals', 'I_F_scoreVenueAdjustedxGoals', 'I_F_flurryScoreVenueAdjustedxGoals', 'I_F_shotsOnGoal', 'I_F_missedShots', 'I_F_blockedShotAttempts', 'I_F_shotAttempts', 'I_F_rebounds', 'I_F_freeze', 'I_F_playStopped', 'I_F_playContinuedInZone', 'I_F_playContinuedOutsideZone', 'penalties', 'I_F_penalityMinutes', 'I_F_faceOffsWon', 'I_F_hits', 'I_F_takeaways', 'I_F_giveaways', 'I_F_lowDangerShots', 'I_F_mediumDangerShots', 'I_F_highDangerShots', 'I_F_lowDangerxGoals', 'I_F_mediumDangerxGoals', 'I_F_highDangerxGoals', 'I_F_scoreAdjustedShotsAttempts', 'I_F_unblockedShotAttempts', 'I_F_scoreAdjustedUnblockedShotAttempts', 'I_F_dZoneGiveaways', 'I_F_xGoalsFromxReboundsOfShots', 'I_F_xGoalsFromActualReboundsOfShots', 'I_F_reboundxGoals', 'I_F_xGoals_with_earned_rebounds', 'I_F_xGoals_with_earned_rebounds_scoreAdjusted', 'I_F_xGoals_with_earned_rebounds_scoreFlurryAdjusted', 'I_F_shifts', 'I_F_oZoneShiftStarts', 'I_F_dZoneShiftStarts', 'I_F_neutralZoneShiftStarts', 'I_F_flyShiftStarts', 'I_F_oZoneShiftEnds', 'I_F_dZoneShiftEnds', 'I_F_neutralZoneShiftEnds', 'I_F_flyShiftEnds', 'faceoffsWon', 'faceoffsLost', 'timeOnBench', 'penalityMinutes', 'penalityMinutesDrawn', 'penaltiesDrawn', 'shotsBlockedByPlayer', 'OnIce_F_xOnGoal', 'OnIce_F_xGoals', 'OnIce_F_flurryAdjustedxGoals', 'OnIce_F_scoreVenueAdjustedxGoals', 'OnIce_F_flurryScoreVenueAdjustedxGoals', 'OnIce_F_shotsOnGoal', 'OnIce_F_missedShots', 'OnIce_F_blockedShotAttempts', 'OnIce_F_shotAttempts', 'OnIce_F_rebounds', 'OnIce_F_lowDangerShots', 'OnIce_F_mediumDangerShots', 'OnIce_F_highDangerShots', 'OnIce_F_lowDangerxGoals', 'OnIce_F_mediumDangerxGoals', 'OnIce_F_highDangerxGoals', 'OnIce_F_scoreAdjustedShotsAttempts', 'OnIce_F_unblockedShotAttempts', 'OnIce_F_scoreAdjustedUnblockedShotAttempts', 'OnIce_F_xGoalsFromxReboundsOfShots', 'OnIce_F_xGoalsFromActualReboundsOfShots', 'OnIce_F_reboundxGoals', 'OnIce_F_xGoals_with_earned_rebounds', 'OnIce_F_xGoals_with_earned_rebounds_scoreAdjusted', 'OnIce_F_xGoals_with_earned_rebounds_scoreFlurryAdjusted', 'OffIce_F_xGoals', 'OffIce_A_xGoals', 'OffIce_F_shotAttempts', 'OffIce_A_shotAttempts', 'xGoalsForAfterShifts', 'xGoalsAgainstAfterShifts', 'corsiForAfterShifts', 'corsiAgainstAfterShifts', 'fenwickForAfterShifts', 'fenwickAgainstAfterShifts']
```

(Note: `I_F_` means "individual for" and `OneIce_F_` means "on ice for". The lower case "x" means "expected".)

I've used one hot encoding on the team and position features using a column transformer, and then built a pipeline to apply standard scaling on all features after the column transformer has been applied, ultimately followed by Ridge regression. But when trying to tune alpha in my Ridge model using `GridSearchCV`, the best cross-validation score is always given by the smallest alpha value I test. Even more strange, setting `alpha=0.01`, the model is able to guess the number of goals scored with an average absolute error of only 0.07, and if we round the predictions to whole numbers, it accurately predicts the number of goals of every player in the test set.

This is obviously nonsense, as the coefficients are enormous (I'm getting numbers like 433835277890.1854) but I can't understand why. I don't see any features in the list that would be "giving away" how many goals the player scored to the model. And just to be 100% sure of this, I check the largest coefficients learned by Ridge; they were `OnIce_F_lowDangerShots` and `OnIce_F_shotsOnGoal` for the largest positive and largest negative coefficients. So nothing that would give away how many goals the player scored.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, Golden Lion. I'll try that out. I would however still like to understand what is happening under the hood here with Ridge. It feels a little cheap to just say that I can't figure it out so I'll use a different model.

Comment: try tpot to find the best classifier for the problem.   with large number of features the classifier can be challenging to find. tpot discovers the best classifier then use randomgridsearch to tune the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
from tpot import TPOTClassifier

tpot=TPOTClassifier(generations=3, population_size=5, verbosity=2, offspring_size=10, scoring='accuracy', cv=5)
tpot.fit(X_train,y_train)

print(tpot.score(X_test,y_test))


generations: iterations to run training
population_size: the number of models to keep after each iteration
offspring_size: number of models to produce in each iteration
mutation_rate: the proportion of pipelines to apply randomness
crossover_rate: the proportion of pipelines to breed each iteration
scoring: the function to determine the best models
cv: cross-validation strategy to use


TPOT is quite unstable when only running with low generations, population size and offspring.
```

> suppose the best classifier is MLPClassifier

then use GridSearch to tune the parameters

> stepwise refinement

another way to tune your parameter is using step wise refinement and see which parameter combinating improves accuracy by iterative trying them and then plotting the results.

> preprocessing

you would normalize your data using standardscaler to remove noise and use simple imputer to fix nan.   find out if any features can be removed by using logistic regression and analyzing the probabilities of the features.